# Populate "SMP" if arrival date is greater than 01-11-2021

Tags: calculated-columns, calculated-field, sharepoint-list

I have a column called `Date_Of_Return`. I want to create a calculate field to return `SMP` if the arrival date is greater than `01-11-2021` and return `JI` if otherwise

I came up with this but its not working effectively.

```
SMP = IF('NEW EUTF UPDATED PORTAL II'[Date_Of_Return] >= DATEVALUE("01-11-2021"),"SMP","JI"())
```

Answer (score 0):

**Please use the below Formula:**

```
=IF([Date_Of_Return] > DATE(2021,11,1), "SMP", "JI")
```

[image]

[image]

`Note:`

**[DATE(year,month,day)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/date-function-b91bef00-4b5b-4ee0-b80e-06e68b1dff29)** - Returns the sequential serial number that represents a particular date.